# Perl IO::Pipe does not work within arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, fork, pipe

im trying the following:

I want to fork multiple processes and use multiple pipes (child -> parent) simultaneously.
My approach is to use IO::Pipe.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use IO::Pipe;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my @ua_processes = (0..9);
my $url = "http://<some-sample-textfile>";
my @ua_pipe;
my @ua_process;

$ua_pipe[0] = IO::Pipe->new();

$ua_process[0] = fork();
if( $ua_process[0] == 0 ) {
    my $response = $ua->get($url);
    $ua_pipe[0]->writer();
    print $ua_pipe[0] $response->decoded_content;
    exit 0;
}

$ua_pipe[0]->reader();
while (<$ua_pipe[0]>) {
    print $_;
}
```

In future i want to use multiple "$ua_process"s in an array.

After execution i got the following errors:

```
Scalar found where operator expected at ./forked.pl line 18, near "] $response"
        (Missing operator before  $response?)
syntax error at ./forked.pl line 18, near "] $response"
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at ./forked.pl line 23.
```

**If i dont use arrays, the same code works perfectly.** It seems only the $ua_pipe[0] dont work as expected (together with a array).

I really dont know why. Anyone knows a solution? Help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
print $ua_pipe[0] $response->decoded_content;
```

The `print` and `say` builtins use the *indirect syntax* to specify the file handle. This allows only for a single scalar variable or a bareword:

```
print STDOUT "foo";
```

or

```
print $file "foo";
```

If you want to specify the file handle via a more complex expression, you have to enclose that expression in curlies; this is called a *dative block*:

```
print { $ua_pipe[0] } $response-decoded_content;
```

This should now work fine.

---

#### Edit

I overlooked the `<$ua_pipe[0]>`. The readline operator `<>` also doubles as the `glob` operator (i.e. does shell expansion for patterns like `*.txt`). Here, the same rules as for `say` and `print` apply: It'll only use the file handle if it is a bareword or a simple scalar variable. Otherwise, it will be interpreted as a glob pattern (implying stringification of the argument). To disambiguate:

- For the readline `<>`, we have to resort to the `readline` builtin:

  ```
  while (readline $ua_pipe[0]) { ... }
  ```
- To force globbing `<>`, pass it a string: `<"some*.pattern">`, or preferably use the `glob` builtin.

Comment: then, the "while (<$ua_pipe[0]>) { ..." gives me only "IO::Pipe::End=GLOB(0x6df0f0)" back...

Comment: Same thing -- the `<$handle>` syntax only works with "simple" filehandle arguments. Try `while (readline($ua_pipe[0])) { ...` instead.

Comment: @at0m33 Oh, sorry, I overlooked that. I just made an edit to my answer, but mob's comment is a good summary.

Comment: Curlies don't help with the `<>` operator. You have to use `readline` or assign the complex expression to a simple expression first (I have made this mistake [more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3016036/168657) [than once](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4305688/168657)).

Comment: For reading, you can also use `$ua_pipe[0]->getline` from the `IO::Handle` API.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks mob and amon, that worked flawlessly now :).

Comment: @mob Thank you for calling me out on that.